# Does ASP.NET Tracing work in MVC2 Views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, trace, asp.net

I have a VS 2010 MVC2 .NET 4.0 web application. ASP.NET tracing is enabled both in the Page directive (Trace="true) and in the Web.config:

```
<trace enabled="true" 
       requestLimit="10"
       pageOutput="true"
       traceMode="SortByTime" 
       localOnly="true" 
       writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true"
       />
```

A standard trace listener is also configured in the Web.config:

```
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
  <listeners>
    <add name="WebPageTrace" type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener, System.Web, Version=4.0.30319.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <add name="TextWriterTrace" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="textListener.log" />
  </listeners> 
</trace>
```

Tracing works fine from the controller, but when I add a Trace in the View (.aspx) nothing ever shows:

```
<% System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Message System.Diagnostics.Trace from View"); %>
<% Page.Trace.Write("Message Page.Trace from View"); %>
```

Is this supposed to work?  Is there something else that is needed to enable Tracing from a View?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328678/asp-net-mvc-tracing-issues

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was answered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328678/asp-net-mvc-tracing-issues) question.  Here was just a bit of the answer provided...

> When you called Trace.Write() in Web
>   Forms, you were interacting with the
>   Trace- Context class. This exists on
>   your ViewPage in ASP.NET MVC, but this
>   isn’t where you would want to  write
>   tracing statements. By the time you’ve
>   passed the baton over to the view,
>   there’s no logic there that you’d need
>   to trace. Instead, you’d like to trace
>   the logic embedded in your controllers

Comment: I expect the answer here is "no, ASP.NET MVC tracing such as this is not supported in views".  Clearly there is a need to have tracing in views on occasion, no matter how well your logic is isolated in a controller.